# static boolean in struct set to wrong value on startup Swift 2.1 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, struct, appdelegate, nskeyedarchiver

I am working on an iOS app and persisting data using `NSKeyedArchiver` and then loading it using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. In a struct titled "WorkingData" I have a static variable named firstLaunch that is set to true. When the app first starts up it is supposed to run the code like this in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of the **AppDelegate**

```
if !WorkingData.firstLaunch
{
    // load settings
}
```

[image]
however firstLaunch is set to false in the symbols table in the debugger and thus the code runs and crashes trying to unwrap an optional. Why is it doing this when it is set to true in code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is as expected, this line of code didn't run yet, so the variable is pointing at nothing and defauls to false. It should work afrer the code is run. If you're still unsure, pring the variable to the console.

Comment: If your logic dictates to check for available data, then... check for available data! This is much more clean, clear and robust.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you access that stored type property it will change to `true`. In your example, when you "step over" the `if` statement, the value will flip and the block with `// load settings` will be skipped. You can also force it to change by typing `po WorkingData.firstLaunch` into the console.